# What is the conversion parameter of Expression.Coalesce for?

Tags: c#, clr, roslyn, expression-trees

For context on this question, please see [the documentation for the Coalesce(Expression, Expression, LambdaExpression) overload of the Expression.Coalesce Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.coalesce?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Coalesce_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_LambdaExpression_). I am referring specifically to the third parameter of this overload. I have a few questions about it for which I have been unable to find answers anywhere, including Microsoft's documentation:

- Why would one choose to use this overload to supply a conversion?
- How will it be used when compiling the expression?
- How should the `LambdaExpression` one passes be constructed (I can only assume a specific parameter signature and return value type will be expected)?

I have repeatedly tried (by casting various lambda functions that employ the `??` operator in code to `Expression<>`) to get the C# compiler to compose an expression tree for me which makes use of this parameter. But every time I use the debugger to check [the corollary property of the conversion parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.conversion?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_BinaryExpression_Conversion) for the expression with `NodeType` `Coalesce` in the resulting tree, it is `null`.

I'm asking because I'm working on a library that works by analyzing expression trees and I need it to properly understand and support these conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can figure out what the C# compiler does by looking at its source and the C# specification.

If you look at [the code in the C# compiler that handles the coalesce expression for expression trees](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/5a95c409/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/LambdaRewriter/ExpressionLambdaRewriter.cs#L782-L795), you'll notice that it only uses `conversion` when the left sub-expression contains a user-defined expression.

You can then look [at the section *The null coalescing operator* of the C# spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-null-coalescing-operator) to see when that happens:

> Specifically, `a ?? b` is processed as follows:
>
> - If `A` exists and is not a nullable type or a reference type, a compile-time error occurs.
> - […]
> - Otherwise, if `b` has a type `B` and an implicit conversion exists from `a` to `B`, the result type is `B`. At run-time, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not null, `a` is unwrapped to type `A0` (if `A` exists and is nullable) and converted to type `B`, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated and becomes the result.
> - […]

So we need type `A` that has implicit user-defined conversion to `B` and use those two types in a null-coalescing expression:

```
class A
{
    public static implicit operator B(A s) => null;
}

class B {}

…

Expression<Func<B>> e = () => new A() ?? new B();
```

If you [decompile this code, you'll see](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAocVoDoAyBLAdgRzQFEAPABwCcBTAZ2qwHsdqFEkQAmVAdiQG8kIgqABYIAWQCGuABQBKAUP6IhKiCQo06jADwgArNoBCAPmMRKEALwQ5VszkoB3CAEFbAfncQHzw3JYqAL5IwazInC58CoIgAMyoAGwQWAC2pAA2WADGWAAuEPSklOQSufTkEH4uENSydt4ArunpLKFsnIYQvIFAA):

```
NewExpression left = Expression.New(typeof(A));
NewExpression right = Expression.New(typeof(B));
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(A), "p");
UnaryExpression body = Expression.Convert(
    parameterExpression, typeof(B),
    (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle((RuntimeMethodHandle)/*OpCode not supported: LdMemberToken*/));
ParameterExpression[] obj = new ParameterExpression[1];
obj[0] = parameterExpression;
Expression.Lambda<Func<B>>(
    Expression.Coalesce(left, right, Expression.Lambda(body, obj)), Array.Empty<ParameterExpression>());
```

Replace `GetMethodFromHandle` with reflection code to get `A.op_Implicit` and you have code to create a valid `Coalesce` expression tree with non-null `Conversion`.

Comment: I do have one other silly question for you. Would you happen to know why this is handled using a lambda expression rather than just the typical means that operator expressions already have for supplying a custom implementation via a MethodInfo object? I'm sure this extra hoop is here for a reason, but knowing why would be enlightening. ;)

Comment: @DanielHenry I don't know, sorry.