# what are the type conversion and lifted call in Expression?

Tags: c#

I'm new to ExpressionTree, below is some source code from `BinaryExpression`:

```
public class BinaryExpression : Expression
{
   internal BinaryExpression(Expression left, Expression right) 
   {
      Left = left;
      Right = right;
   }
   
   public Expression Left { get; }
   public Expression Right { get; }
   // ...
   public bool IsLifted { get; }
   public LambdaExpression Conversion => GetConversion();
   internal virtual LambdaExpression? GetConversion() => null;
 
}
```

I don't quite understand what are type conversion and lifted call and why we need them, can someone show me an concrete example?

Comment: Seen [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.islifted) yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About C# Expression.MakeBinary(),how to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080444/about-c-sharp-expression-makebinary-how-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

**Lifted operator calls:**

> An operator call is lifted if the operator expects non-nullable operands but nullable operands are passed to it. <sub>([BinaryExpression.IsLifted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.islifted))</sub>

Example: If `a` and `b` are `int?`, `a + b` is a lifted call of `Int32`'s `+` operator.

---

**Conversion:**

> Gets the type conversion function that is used by a coalescing or compound assignment operation. <sub>([BinaryExpression.Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.conversion))</sub>

This property is needed for expressions of type `a ?? b`, when there is an implicit user-defined conversion from `a`'s type to `b`'s type. A detailed answer and a concrete example can be found in this related question:

- [What is the conversion parameter of Expression.Coalesce for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53588703/87698)